# Java: How to add a JSON object to a JSON array only if one of the elements don't already exist

Tags: java, arrays, json, key-value

Say I have a JSON array (inside of a JSON object) of JSON objects.

```
{
  data:
    [
      {id:45, building:1, lane: 6},
      {id:58, building:1, lane: 9},
      {id:46, building:2, lane: 4},
      {id:51, building:2, lane: 9},
      {id:40, building:3, lane: 2},
      {id:39, building:4, lane: 3}
  ]
}
```

I want to cycle through the array and add each JSON object to a new JSON array, but ONLY if one of the values of a certain key (`building`) hasn't already been added to the new JSON array.

For example, if I iterate over the JSON array and get to `id:45`, I want to add that object to my new JSON array, but only if there isn't already an object with a key-value pair of `building:1`. Since it'd be the first object, it would get added into the new array.

Let's say the second object I was iterating over was `id:58`. Being that my new JSON array already has an object with `building:1`, I would not want to add that object to my new array.

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Did you try any approach from yourself so that we can check & give some solutions?

Comment: Sure. I'll update.

Comment: You should use a HashSet  storing  your data using the id as the key  so that you avoid duplicates, concerning the json iteration check this example https://www.edureka.co/community/7982/iterate-over-a-jsonobject

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not test this myself but it should work.

```
    JSONArray arr = //your data object
    JSONArray newArr = new JSONArray();
    arr.stream().forEach(el -> {
        Integer val = (Integer) ((JSONObject) el).get("building");
        if (((List<Integer>) newArr.parallelStream().map(obj -> (Integer) ((JSONObject) obj).get("building"))
                .filter(obj -> obj == val).collect(Collectors.toList())).isEmpty()) {
            newArr.add(el);
        }
    });
```